# c# excel how to freeze multiple rows

Tags: c#, excel

I can easily freeze the first row in an excel sheet by using

workSheet.Application.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = true;

but I need to freeze rows 3-7.  How can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by freezing rows 3-7? Are rows one and two hidden?

Comment: No they are just logos.  I would like when the user scrolls the 3-7 stays frozen,  1-7 can be frozen too. But workSheet.Application.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = true; freezes just the first row.

Comment: One way to find out how to do odd things in Excel is to open Excel, record a macro that does what you want, then look at the VBA it recorded. Whatever it does in VBA, you can do the same with Excel Interop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't freeze just rows 3-7. You have to pick a row and freeze everything above it. The only way you could freeze 3-7 is if rows 1 and 2 are hidden.

To freeze rows 1-7:

```
workSheet.Application.ActiveSheet.Rows[8].Select();
workSheet.Application.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = true;
```